# Javascript actions always pulling first table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

On my page I have two table both having the export tools that will export the table into a CSV file. When I go to export the table it will only export the first table is there a way to get the correct table? Do I need to add something like closest table?

> oTableByClassTable2 is a group of three tables how would I just get the one selected?

[image]

```
   JS
    $('.report2_tools > li > a.tool-action').on('click', function () {
        debugger;
        var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
        debugger;
        oTableByClassTable2.DataTable().button(action).trigger();
        debugger;
    });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="actions">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right report2_tools">
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:;" data-action="0" class="tool-action">
                <i class="icon-printer"></i> csv
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered report2">
                  </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right report2_tools">
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:;" data-action="0" class="tool-action">
                <i class="icon-printer"></i> csv
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered report2">
                  </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Data-action is 0 for both tables?

Comment: Correct I have it 0 set for both and also tried increment it by one but it still will not get the correct table

Comment: When It is incremented table two will not export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [DataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/button().) button selector documentation, what you see is by design.

> Important: If the selectors used result in more that one button being selected, this method will automatically truncate the result to the first button found only.

Other types of selectors are more relevant to your example such as buttons()

Alternatively you can give each of the tables a different unique id and instead select using the id then call the button trigger.

```
<table id="tbl1"></table>
.....
$('.tbl1').DataTable().button().trigger()
```